# How hard is it to run The Enemy Within using WFRP 2ed rules?

Tags: published-adventures, conversion, wfrp-2e, wfrp-1e

I was thinking about starting the WFRP 1ed campaign The Enemy Within but using the WFRP 2ed rules which I believe are much better. We used to play WFRP 1ed before WFRP 2ed was released but we never started The Enemy Within campaign, however now the time seems perfect as we had a 2 year break from Warhammer and we will be making new characters.

Are there any pitfalls I should watch for? How hard is it to convert the game mechanics (e.g. enemies stats) from WFRP 1ed to WFRP 2ed? From what I remember The Enemy Within was a very good campaign and could be worth playing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done almost exactly that, except I also had some house-rules in combat mechanics. This was around 5 years ago, so the particulars are a little hazy. In general, I think, it was pretty straightforward - as far as I remember I converted stats basically on the fly, without any special preparation.

Comment: And how about spell casting and magic? magic in WFRP 2ed is much stronger because of recent war with chaos hordes, did you modify the rules or did you stick with the 2ed rules?

Comment: @Pawel As far as I remember we switched completely to 2ed rules. I think I had some problems with enemies/NPCs having spells listed that did not exist in 2ed or made no sense, but I mostly ignored those and it kinda worked. I also seem to remember that I'd bungled magic rules in general, though (-8

Comment: Second this answer. I've done it as well and it works pretty well. Since the campaign starts out with low-level characters, power levels especially in magic don't really come into play that much.